# Regex check for words and words with spaces separating letters

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-match-all, profanity

So I have an array of profanities that I am checking for in a string.

E.g.

```
$string = 'naughty string';
$words = [
    'naughty',
    'example',
    'words'
];
$pattern = '/('.join($words, '|').')/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
$matched = implode(', ', $matches[0]);
```

But I also want to check profanities split with spaces:

E.g.

**n a u g h t y**

Yes I can do this by adding it to the array:

```
$words = [
    'naughty',
    'n a u g h t y',
    'example',
    'e x a m p l e',
    'words',
    'w o r d s'
];
```

But I have a huge array of "bad" words and was wondering if there is any easy way of doing this?

------ EDIT ------

So this isn't meant to be super accurate. For my application every space is a new line.. So a string like this: **n a u g h t y string** would result in this:

n

a

u

g

h

t

y

string

Comment: I think that you are asking too much here.. What if I spelt a naughty word slightly wrong, but is stil looked naughty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question as asked, create a pattern like `b\s*a\s*d` instead of just `bad`:

```
$string = 'some bad and b a d and more ugly and very u g l y words';

$words = [
    'bad',
    'ugly'
];

$pattern = '/\b(' . join(
    array_map(function($w) {
        return join(str_split($w), '\s*');
    }, $words), '|') .'\b)/i';

print preg_replace($pattern, '***', $string); 
// some *** and *** and more *** and very *** words
```

On a more general note, you can't reliably remove profanities, especially in the unicode world. There's no way you can filter out something like `ƒⓤçκ`.

Comment: This is spot on! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Encode the words into the array with `\s?` to match optional spaces, like so:

```
$words = [
    'n\s?a\s?u\s?g\s?h\s?t\s?y',
    'e\s?x\s?a\s?m\s?p\s?l\s?e',
    'w\s?o\s?r\s?d\s?s',
];
```

Or you could use `\s*` to match any number of spaces.

If you are unfamiliar with the nuances of regular expressions, I would recommend having a look at https://regex101.com/